# How acls really work on linux?

Tags: linux, debian, acl

I'm trying to give read/write access on a folder to my user without success, even after setting **ACLs**

Here is my directory listing :

```
[root@hostname]/h/admin # ❯❯❯ ll  /var/
total 40K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4.0K Jun 23 06:25 backups
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4.0K Jun 11 10:31 cache
drwxr-xr-x  29 root root  4.0K Jun 11 10:30 lib
drwxrwsr-x   2 root staff 4.0K Jun 11  2014 local
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4.0K Jul  3 06:27 log
drwxrwsr-x   2 root mail  4.0K Jul 19  2014 mail
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4.0K Jul 19  2014 opt
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4.0K Jul 19  2014 spool
drwxrwxrwt   2 root root  4.0K Jul  3 06:27 tmp
drwxrwxr-x+  2 root root  4.0K Jul  1 16:14 www
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 Jul 19  2014 lock -> /run/lock
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     4 Jul 19  2014 run -> /run
```

ACLs :

```
[root@hostname]/h/admin # ❯❯❯ getfacl /var/www
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/www
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:newuser:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Trying to create a file in **/var/www/** folder

```
[root@hostname]/h/admin # ❯❯❯ su newuser
newuser@hostname:/home/admin$ touch /var/www/test.txt
touch: cannot touch `/var/www/test.txt': Permission denied
newuser@hostname:/home/admin$
```

I have the same error even if I change the ownership of **/var/www** to apache user.

I would like to know what's wrong.

My distribution is debian.

Thanks.

Comment: eh? Both the std permissions and facls say this directory is not writable by anyone other than the root user and root group. You didn't tell us what groups new_user is in, but they shouldn't be in the root group. Your system is behaving exactly the way I would expect it to.

Comment: I don't why I have this : `default:group::r-x` maybe the problem is there, but the **setfacl** command doesn't specify anywhere that the user being granted right has to be in the same group as the group to whom the file belongs. This the command I ran : `setfacl -dRm u:newuser:rwx /var/www` . And my aim is not to add **newuser** to **root** group.

Comment: I set default group right to the folder : `setfacl -d -m g::rwx /var/www`
But it's still not working . there is no **user:newuser:rwx** in the **getfacl** output, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: I found the problem. It's due to linux setfacl **version 2.2.51**. In this new version, the **-d** (**default**) option used for right inheritance doesn't work and set the right of the to the default ones. In **version 2.2.4** it works appropriately and fine. Now I don't know yet how to solve the issue.